# Http version of Stack Overflow doesn't show icons

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stack-overflow, cdn

Recently, the http version of Stack Overflow doesn't show voting icons. This is due to a XML error in the svg file that's being served.

To reproduce:

1. Go to [Dictionaries and files in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28710790/dictionaries-and-files-in-python) for example (just picked the top one in my list on the frontpage)
2. In Firebug or Chrome dev, highlight the missing vote arrow and locate the cdn url for the background image (in my case http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg?v=1bc6a0c03b68)
3. Open that url in a new tab, it will produce

   > XML Parsing Error: syntax error
   >   Location: http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg?v=1bc6a0c03b68
   >   Line Number 1, Column1: 
   >   3-1.7c2,0,3.4,0.8,4.3,1.7c1.2,1.3,1.6,2.9,1.6,5.3C169.7,40.5,169.4,42,168.2,43.3z M165.5,34.6

If you change the url to https://, it will work as it should.

Solution would probably be to redirect http to https for stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Can't reproduce this in Chrome 41.0.2272.64 beta on Xubuntu 14.10.